# float issue - 2 elements with float:right style causing a div placed in between them to move to the left

Tags: css, css-float

I have 2 links and each of them have **style="float:right"** . I have another **div** element in between these two links.
Now , in IE7 , the 2 links are displaying properly whereas the div in between is pushed to the left.
Here's the code :

```
<a style="float:right" href="javascript:exportqueryresulttocsv();">Export Query Result to CSV</a>
<div style="overflow:auto">
    <!-- I have a table displaying a report here -->
</div>
<a style="float:right" href="javascript:exportqueryresulttocsv();">Export Query Result To CSV</a>
```

[image]

What is the problem in positioning these divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you wanting it look like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/8NTt3/10/

if so float all the items to the right, but use a clearfix between each element. eg

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

so float them all right, they should align evenly